# How to rewrite RenderScript code in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, renderscript, gaussianblur

I have this piece of code in Android that given an int value, performs some image processing (blur effect) using `RenderScript`. While it is super fast and efficient, it is deprecated so I am looking for other alternatives. What's another efficient way to rewrite it? Probably a GPU-based solution with similar or even faster performance?

I tried `RenderEffect` but couldn't find a way to apply it on a Bitmap and not ImageView.

```
private void processImage (int value)
{
    try
    {
        RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(context);
        Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurEffect = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, Element.U8_4(rsScript));
        blurEffect.setRadius(value);
        blurEffect.setInput(alloc);

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, output);

        blurEffect.forEach(outAlloc);
        outAlloc.copyTo(output);

        rsScript.destroy();
        output.getPixels(bitmap, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate#built-in is a great way to migrate off of the `ScriptIntrinsic` functionality to something that is supported. There's other information on that page too about how to convert more complex examples. Good luck! (And thank you for actually heeding the deprecation warning)

Comment: Thanks. I looked into rendereffect, but it only applies to imageview. I need to apply to Bitmap. Can you provide code to show if it is possible?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate#migrate-from-blur is probably the better suggestion, since it uses the exact same API structure as the original intrinsics, while the other options on that page are indeed different APIs (some of which don't have Bitmap as an input option as you mentioned). Can you try that particular option?

Comment: Interesting. Idk why I have to build the toolkit myself instead of just putting it on google repo. Btw, it says "These functions execute multithreaded on the CPU". I wish it was on GPU.